# Why, given a linear transformation $L:V\rightarrow W$ and basis $B$ for $V$, when $L(B)=\dim(W)$ then $L(B)$ is a basis for $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand a proof for the following proposition: given a linear transformation $L:V\rightarrow W$ between finite vector spaces $V$ and $W$, $\dim(V)=\dim(W)=n$, if $L$ is injective then it is an isomorphism. The proof goes like this: let $B$ be a basis for $V$. Since $B$ is lin. indep. and $L$ is injective, it takes $B$ to a lin. indep. set, i.e. $L(B)$ is lin. indep. Then since $|L(B)|=n=\dim(W)$, $L(B)$ is a basis for $W$ and $L$ is surjective.

I am not sure how the last statement is formed. In particular, how does $|L(B)|=\dim(W)$ imply that $L(B)$ is a basis for $W$? As for the finishing statement am I right that $L(B)$ being a basis for $W$ means the image of $L$ is the same as its codomain, which implies surjectivity?

Comment: You have a linearly independent set for $W$ that has cardinality $n = \dim(W)$. This is the definition of a basis for $W$. Was this your confusion? Or are you wondering why $L$ being injective implies $L(B)$ is linearly independent?

Comment: The definition for a basis that I go by is a set of elements which is lin. indep. and spanning. My confusion was why $n=\dim(W)$ implies spanning, but the answer below cleared that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st Question:**

Given that $\dim(V)=\dim(W)=n$.
Let $B=\{b_1,b_2,\ldots, b_n\}$ be a basis of $V$.
To show $L(B)$ is a basis for $W$.

We first show that the set $L(B)=\{L(b_1),L(b_2),\dots, L(b_n)\}$ is linearly independent.

Let $c_1L(b_1)+c_2L(b_2)+\cdots+c_nL(b_n)=0 $

$\implies L(c_1b_1)+L(c_2b_2)+\cdots +L(c_nb_n)=0$

$\implies L(c_1b_1+c_2b_2+\cdots +c_nb_n)=0=L(0)$

Since $L$ is injective so $c_1b_1+c_2b_2+\cdots +c_nb_n=0$.

Since $B$ is a basis of $V$ and $b_i$'s are linearly independent, we have $c_i=0 \forall i.$

**2nd Question:**

Now $L(B)\subset W$ is a linearly independent set of $W$ having $n$ elements. We show that $L(B)$ spans $W$, i.e. every element of $W$ is a linear combination of members of $L(B)$.

Let $w\in W$. If $w\notin \text{span}(L(B))$, then $\{w,L(b_1),L(b_2),\dots, L(b_n)\}$ is a linearly independent set of $W$,  which is false as $W$ can have atmost $n$ linearly independent elements since $\dim(W)=n$.

Comment: That makes sense, but now am I right on my conclusion for surjectivity or is there some other reason?

Comment: @ShivashriganeshMahato; yes you are correct,